# how to post the value of the following switch button

Tags: php, html, css

full code here : https://codepen.io/asmoun0801/pen/mGegjw

```
<div class="">
    <p>Certifiée :</p>
    <!-- Rounded switch -->
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: So have you actually tried anything? Any ideas?

Comment: Generally to POST a form element's value you need: (1) A `name` for the form element. (2) A form.  You don't have either of these.  Given the latter, it's not entirely clear what you mean by "post".  Where are you posting it *to*?

Comment: Hi, to start you haven't defined your form tags starting like `<form action="" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, you should place the `<input>` element inside a

```
<form method="POST" action=""> ... </form>
```

element in order to be able to POST it to a PHP server. Also you should set the name attribute of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

css : https://codepen.io/asmoun0801/pen/eLJOXg
solution html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  if(isset($_POST['cert'])){
 echo $cert[0] ;
 }   
?>
<form action="action.php"  method="post">
<div class="">
<p>Certifiée :</p>
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" name="cert[]" value="true">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```